# Can chrome running on Windows submit authentication details to auto-login?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a web app/site which uses AD as an authentication store. Users can now use the same credentials to login the our web site apps as they do to login to Windows.

However it would be nice, if Chrome could somehow obtain those details and submit them to the server automagically, via an extension or something???

That way if someone visits the web site while logged in to Windows machine within our network they do not have to re-enter the password, hoever if accessed externally, they still have to login to the web site.

What needs to happen to make this a reality? Chrome is our browser of choice.

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication sounds like what I am after (Integrated Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should be required since Chrome supports this natively as does IE and even Firefox (though it may need a little coaxing).

If it isn't happening, I can think of several possibilities:

- You have a firewall in the way blocking the authentication handshake
- The AD on the web server isn't in the same domain as the Windows login domain - so the credentials being passed are not, in fact, valid. This isn't a show-stopper since the Windows Credential store can keep the appropriate credentials if asked to by the user. Alternatively, you could create a one-way trust so that the AD that the web server uses trusts the authentication provided by the Windows login AD.
- Although using AD, the web server isn't, in fact, using Windows credentials to authenticate but some other mechanism such as OAuth or even a forms-based login using a separate data store.

Where is the web server in relation to the Windows domain and the user? Are they all on the same internal network or is the web server outside your corporate network?